# Filtering a table using another table/list although matches must be done as a Contains, i.e. a SQL Like join. Is this possible via join, DAX, or M?

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, m

I have a large table of devices and a second tiny table of search terms. I would like to filter the list of devices searching as a substring in the Device column or the Group column. I'm not sure if PQ can do Like Joins similar to SQL or if it is better to do this in DAX or M both of which I'm new to anyway. I've found a couple of online examples claiming to do something similar to what I want, but the M code was confusing and their descriptions on the solutions didn't make sense according to many others on the posts.

Can anyone give me some advice. I'm not sure what the performance will be like to do this in PQ. Executing a SQL query would be better, but isn't an option at present.

Thanks in advance.

E.g.: If the Search list is made up of ("server", "load", "uk") then I want to filter the Devices table on either the Device or Group columns looking for any row that contains them as case insensitive substrings, i.e. ("%server%", "%load%", "%uk%")

Search list (named range - not fixed number of entries, might be empty): -

| Column1 |
| --- |
| server |
| load |
| uk |

Devices table (100k+ rows): -

| Row | Device | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EP1-uk | null |
| 2 | UKG545DEV | Server3 |
| 3 | L123 | Load Balancer |
| 4 | L678 | Load Balancer |
| 5 | cak.co.uk | Site |
| 6 | GBPRD996 | Backup |
| 7 | BLTSTLOL | DRaaS |
| 8 | 232.156 | Foo-UK-WACK |
| 9 | Server4 | Got bored |

Filtered Devices table (rows 6 and 7 removed): -

| Row | Device | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EP1-uk | null |
| 2 | UKG545DEV | Server3 |
| 3 | L123 | Load Balancer |
| 4 | L678 | Load Balancer |
| 5 | cak.co.uk | Site |
| 8 | 232.156 | Foo-UK-WACK |
| 9 | Server4 | Got bored |

That's it. Hopefully simple.

Comment: provide sample data and expected output to start with.

Comment: @smpa01 Added sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PQ supports joins.

This is another example for joining for your reference:

[Excel MERGE two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509957/excel-merge-two-tables/72511447#72511447)

For more “flexible” match:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Merge-with-wildcards/m-p/581823

Answer (score 0):

PQ has a fuzzy join which might be what you're looking for. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-fuzzy-match-power-query-ffdd5082-c0c8-4c8e-a794-bd3962b90649

Alternatively, you can hand craft your own "like" join if you really need to. If you post sample data and desired output, someone will post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how efficient this is, but this will search all columns to see if any of them contain any text from your lookup list, case ignored. Then just filter that column

Works by (a) combining all columns on the row into one long text (b) bringing in the search list (c) transforming the search list using Text.Contains to find a match

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
TestTable=Table.Buffer(Lookup), //name of your lookup table query
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom",  each 
let test = Text.Combine(List.Transform(Record.ToList(_), each Text.From(_))," ") in  
List.AnyTrue( List.Transform(TestTable[Column1], each Text.Contains(test, _, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in SQL you would do it the following way. You are not doing any join here. It is simple filtering.

Re: Performance - Depends on what you want to do? Is the is data-level or analysis-level? If later, then surely DAX. If prior and if you have a premium workspace take your data to **`datamart`** and you can apply fully qualified SQL there. In general, DAX has a much superior performance than PQ. PQ is not scalable with large data the same way SQL/DAX is.

```
select 
  * 
from 
  @t1 
where 
  c2 like '%server%' 
  or c2 like '%load%' 
  or c3 like '%server' 
  or c3 like '%load%'
```

[image: s1]

**The same can be replicated in a Dax Query**

```
Table =
CALCULATETABLE (
    Devices,
    CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Device], "server" )
        || CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Device], "load" )
        || CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Device], "uk" )
        || CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Group], "server" )
        || CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Group], "load" )
        || CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Group], "uk" )
)
```

[image: s2]

or better through a measure

```
maxRow =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Devices[Row] ),
    FILTER (
        Devices,
        CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Device], SELECTEDVALUE ( CAT[Column1] ) )
            || CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Group], SELECTEDVALUE ( CAT[Column1] ) )
    )
)
```

[image: s3]

**ALL at once**

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Devices[Row] ),
    GENERATE (
        CAT,
        FILTER (
            Devices,
            CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Device], CALCULATE ( MAX ( CAT[Column1] ) ) )
                || CONTAINSSTRING ( Devices[Group], CALCULATE ( MAX ( CAT[Column1] ) ) )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: s4]

Comment: I mention the SQL join because I don't know how many entries will be in the Search table - it might be empty. I don't expect that there will be that many. So instead of trying to create a dynamic OR list the LIKE join would easily do the task albeit not very quickly. The measure solution you gave looks interesting. I don't understand it, but will try. Your image suggests that I have to select a value from the list. Will this execute for all values in the Search lookup list? I'm not using Power BI rather the filtered data will reurn to Excel so this still the same?

Comment: Yes, you need to make a selection from the slicer and the measure will act accordingly.

Comment: Ah, I need the data filtered to all values as substrings instead of simply one. Is that change possible with the measure you posted?

Comment: Sure can. Updated the answer, in that case, the slicer will be useless.